# How to correctly upload an image with WhatsApp API (meta) with C#?

Tags: c#, http, curl, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am trying to upload an image with WhatsApp API in a visual studio project. The following curl command runs correctly when run in the terminal/cmd in Windows 7:

```
curl --insecure   POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/********/media" ^
-H "Authorization: Bearer ********" ^
-F "file=@\"C:/dune2.jpg\"" ^
-F "type=\"image/jpeg\"" ^
-F "messaging_product=\"whatsapp\""
```

I've sent text messages and linked files (with http links) with the API commands (according to the documentation) in C# without any issue, but when trying to upload an image, it seems that there is something missing in the HTTP request:

```
string token = "*********";
idTelefono = "*********";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/" + idTelefono + "/media");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\Windows Libraries\\Desktop\\dune2.jpg")), "file",Path.GetFileName("D:\\Windows Libraries\\Desktop\\dune2.jpg"));
content.Add(new StringContent("image/jpeg"), "type");
content.Add(new StringContent("whatsapp"), "messaging_product");
request.Content = content;

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
MessageBox.Show(responseBody);
```

I get the error:

> "(#100) Param files must be a file with one of the following types: (HERE GOES A LONG LIST OF FORMAT/TYPES)... Received file of type ".", "type":"OAuthException","code":100...

Do I need to codify the file differently, or add an extra `type` parameter somewhere in the content?
Note: adding a `Content-type` header messes all up so it's not a header related issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, it seems that while using "ByteArrayContent", the content type was not being specified, so I used "StreamContent" instead, as follows:

```
MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var imageContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("D:\\Windows Libraries\\Desktop\\dune2.jpg"));
imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
content.Add(imageContent, "file", Path.GetFileName("D:\\Windows Libraries\\Desktop\\dune2.jpg"));
```

The Mime type was necessary.